# Readonly DataContract

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, wcf

What difference does it make if I make a property of my DataContract readonly? like below.

```
[DataContract]
public class data
{
  [DataMember]
  public string datestring 
  { 
     get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); } 
  }
  //
  // Other proprties
  //
}
```

My Jquery request to WCF service was getting Aborted everytime, and when I removed this readonly property it worked. So why can't I make a property like this in my DataContract of WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no explanation for the reason, the documentation for [DataMemberAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

"Properties to which the DataMemberAttribute attribute has been applied must have both get and set fields; they cannot be get-only or set-only."

**Edit**

I was curious as to why this was the case, so did a little searching.  I ran across this in a forum:

"it needs to be get/set so that the values can be assigned when it is being transported across application boundaries." (taken from [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?561294-RESOLVED-Unable-to-use-ReadOnly-Properties-in-WCF-DataContract)).

The author of that forum post also indicates you could use a private setter on the property to workaround this issue:

```
[DataMember]
public string datestring
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
    }
    private set
    {
    }
}
```

Note the above code is untested, but should work.